# Firefox do not store cookies from twitch.tv

Tags: firefox, 21.10

I installed Ubuntu 21.10. Whenever I open twitch.tv, there is a box "We value your privacy" with an option "Accept cookies".
Unfortunatelly, it works until reopen page.

How to accept cookies permanently?

Firefox is 93.0 Mozilla Firefox snap for Ubuntu Canonical-002.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is solved by using .deb version of firefox